# How can I tell Require.js to use the same paths and shims for multiple mains?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

We have a suite of similar apps, all being built from the same codebase. There are currently 5 different main.js files, and they all repeat the same

```
requirejs.config({
  paths: { foo foo foo },
  shim: { bar bar bar }
});
```

in each main. Ideally, I could keep this DRY by only defining these values once. Is it possible to define them somewhere external to the main.js file?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Delete 4 of these files and change your  tags from:

```
<script data-main="js/main1.js" src="[requirejs path]"></script>
<script data-main="js/main2.js" src="[requirejs path]"></script>
<script data-main="js/main3.js" src="[requirejs path]"></script>
<script data-main="js/main4.js" src="[requirejs path]"></script>
<script data-main="js/main5.js" src="[requirejs path]"></script>
```

to

```
<script data-main="js/main1.js" src="[requirejs path]"></script>
<script data-main="js/main1.js" src="[requirejs path]"></script>
<script data-main="js/main1.js" src="[requirejs path]"></script>
<script data-main="js/main1.js" src="[requirejs path]"></script>
<script data-main="js/main1.js" src="[requirejs path]"></script>
```

Then put a small inline  snippet in each file that launches a specific app, e.g.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require(['app1'], function(App) { App.init() }) 
</script>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require(['app2'], function(App) { App.init() }) 
</script>
```

etc

Comment: How could this result in running different apps?

Answer (score 0):

I've created my own personal distribution of Require.JS for this purpose.

It is basically the original Require.JS code with the configuration (paths and shims) concatenated to the bottom. It means my projects never have to declare where to find jQuery, etc. Pretty handy.

Note: my individual projects may still call `require.config` in order to set project-specific locations, etc. This is technically calling it a second time (as the first time was called when loading Require.JS) but it works fine according to my tests.